# How to use pytest capsys on tests that have mocking decorators?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, python-decorators

I have being trying to find a way to use mocking decorators and pytest capsys at the same time but I wasn't able to find the right way to do it.

```
import pytest
import requests_mock


@requests_mock.mock()
def test_with_mock(m):
    pass

def test_with_capsys(capsys):
    pass


# how to write a test that works with both?
```

Answer (score 11):

As stated in the [`request-mock`'s docs](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytest.html):

> `pytest` has its own method of registering and loading custom fixtures. `requests-mock` provides an external fixture registered with `pytest` such that it is usable simply by specifying it as a parameter. There is no need to import `requests-mock` it simply needs to be installed and specify the argument `requests_mock`.
>
> The fixture then provides the same interface as the `requests_mock.Mocker` letting you use `requests-mock` as you would expect.
>
> ```
> >>> import pytest
> >>> import requests
>
> >>> def test_url(requests_mock):
> ...     requests_mock.get('http://test.com', text='data')
> ...     assert 'data' == requests.get('http://test.com').text
> ...
> ```

So just use the `requests_mock` fixture instead of the decorator:

```
def test_with_mock_and_capsys(requests_mock, capsys):
    pass
```

#### Background

`pytest` doesn't play along with function decorators that add positional arguments to the test function. `pytest` considers all arguments that

- aren't bound to an instance or type as in instance or class methods;
- don't have default values;
- aren't bound with `functools.partial`;
- aren't replaced with `unittest.mock` mocks

to be replaced with fixture values, and will fail if it doesn't find a suitable fixture for any argument. So stuff like

```
import functools
import pytest


def deco(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args += ('spam',)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@deco
def test_spam(spam_arg):
    assert True
```

will fail, and this is exactly what `requests-mock` does. A workaround to that would be passing the mocker via keyword args:

```
import pytest
import requests_mock


@requests_mock.Mocker(kw='m')
def test_with_mock_and_fixtures(capsys, **kwargs):
    m = kwargs['m']
    ...
```

but since `requests-mock` already offers a fixture, why bother using the decorator?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of requests-mock. Thanks for answering, I'm going to link people to this from now on. Do you mind if i just wholesale copy that background snippet into the documentation?

Comment: Sure, glad the example was helpful!