# How to fake my response in pytest requests mock

Tags: python, pytest, requests-mock

My function that I am trying to test is returning `list` of `strings`:

```
def listForumsIds:
    response = requests.get(url)
    forums= response.json().get('forums')
    forumsIds= [forum['documentId'] for forum in forums]
    # return like: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'.....]
    return forumsIds
```

My test function:

```
@requests_mock.mock()
def test_forms(self, m):
    # I also used json='response'
    m.get('valid url', text="response", status_code=200)
    resp = listForumsIds('valid url')
    # ERROR !!!!
    assert resp == "response"
```

I am getting error like: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` or `str object has no attribute get`

How to fake my response to be match return value of my function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pytest capsys on tests that have mocking decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060950/how-to-use-pytest-capsys-on-tests-that-have-mocking-decorators)

Comment: @hoefling NO, it is not simialr, basically how am I tell the mock that my request return wont be just text='text' or just json='response', it is json object that I will get the forums header and inside it ill get all forums IDs

Comment: What are you testing for? the `get` method from json? You should be mocking as per @hoefling's answer. You could be looking into `pytest.patch.object` for mocking request and json methods as well (with a `returned_value` argument)

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the desired payload in the `json` field of the mocked response. Example, adapted to your code:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @requests_mock.mock()
    def test_forms(self, m):
        payload = {"forums": [{"documentId": "id1"}]}
        m.register_uri("GET", "https://www.example.com", json=payload)
        ids = listForumsIds('https://www.example.com')
        assert ids == ['id1']
```

Comment: This answer is the best of all since it covers the basic yet crucial hint that we have to register the API URL we want to mock. Thank you @hoefling